# allow user to type in 1 or more quantity using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
quantity = $('div.ProductNameText').text().match(/Exclusive Handmade Box/g).length;
if(quantity)
{ 
   $("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", quantity);
}
```

I would like to make it so that the user can enter 1 or MORE.
At the moment it forces the quantity box to display ONLY 1.

Any ideas?

edit: more info: the div class is the product title and im just trying to check that product exists then allowing the user to enter 1 or MORE into the quantity text box.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where exactly is the user entering data? Is it an input or a select? An HTML snippet would be helpful.

Comment: its just a quantity text box..

Comment: Does "MORE" mean the literal string "MORE" or numbers larger than 1? Should we use a drop-down list instead?

Comment: we cant use a drop down list box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#kitProduct #Quantity").keyup(function() {
    var quantity = parseInt($.trim($(this).val()));
    if (!quantity || qantity < 1 || !quantity.length) {
        $(this).val('1');
    } else {
        $(this).val(quantity);
    }
});
```

Comment: can i have a quick explanation to how this code works please?

Comment: @PD24 `keypress()` event fires when user give input using key board and in each keypress it checks the value that user given and if user gives less that 1 then it set 1 to input(within `if()` condition) else it set the value as user gives(within `else` condition)

Comment: please check the answer, it doesnt seem to work.. it forces 1.. what about if the user wants to enter 3?

Answer (score 0):

PD, I believe that

```
quantity = $('div.ProductNameText').text().match(/Exclusive Handmade Box/g).length;
```

Will only return 1 for any single quantity 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. You are checking the length of the text; not the value of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how would i force the user to enter only 1 or more? i.e they might want 4 items so they enter 4.